# How to use setInterval/setTimeout in Dart SDK 0.4+

Tags: dart, dart-html

I realised that in current Dart SDK version 0.4.1.0_r19425 methods like `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `clearTimeout`, `clearInterval` aren't part of [`Window`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Window.html) class any more and they all moved to [`WorkerContext`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/WorkerContext.html).
Is there any documentation on how to use them now? Do I need to create a new instance of `WorkerContext` every time I want to use them?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In addition to Timer mentioned by Chris, there is a [Future-based](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/03/new-asynchronous-apis-for-dart.html) API:

```
var future = new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), doStuffCallback);
```

There is not yet direct support for cancelling a Future callback, but this works pretty well:

```
var future = new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10));
var subscription = future.asStream().listen(doStuffCallback);
// ...
subscription.cancel();
```

Hopefully, there will soon be a [Stream version of Timer.repeating](http://dartbug.com/8477) as well.

Comment: So if I understand it right, using Future is the recommend way.

Answer (score 30):

You can use:

**1) SetInterval**

```
_timer = new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), functionBack);

Where: `functionBack(Timer timer) {
  print('again');
}
```

**2) SetTimeOut**

```
_timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => print('done'));

Where _time is type Time
```

Answer (score 14):

From this [post on the group](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/misc/9h7pxLbv5fU) (Feb 14th 2013).

```dart
// Old Version
window.setTimeout(() { doStuff(); }, 0);

// New Version
import 'dart:async';
Timer.run(doStuffCallback);
```

And another example (copied from the same post)

```dart
// Old version: 
var id = window.setTimeout(doStuffCallback, 10);
.... some time later....
window.clearTimeout(id);

id = window.setInterval(doStuffCallback, 1000);
window.clearInterval(id);

// New version:
var timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), doStuffCallback);
... some time later ---
timer.cancel();

timer = new Timer.repeating(const Duration(seconds: 1), doStuffCallback);
timer.cancel();
```

Specifically, they are now part of the `Timer` class in the `dart:async` library (rather than `WorkerContext`, which seems to be IndexedDb specific).  [API docs here](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Timer.html)

Comment: I caution against using timer, unless you put try/catch inside Timer. If an exception is thrown inside Timer, and you don't catch it, game over and app over. You probably want to use Future.delayed, which not only catches exceptions correctly, but also gives you a handle to know when it's actually done. Futures compose better, too.