# How to get keyboard user input within a timeframe

Tags: dart

For example I want to provide user with a prompt 
`print("do this within 3 seconds or time will be up.")`

And when time 3 second passes, it should prompt another message saying,
`print("Your time is up, you failed.")`

So far I have figured out to get the current time using `DateTime current = new DateTime();` and the three seconds later time with `DateTime threeSeconds = current.add(new Duration (seconds : 3));`
 but I can't figure out how to force user to enter something within those two times.

Comment: Most javascript libraries have timers and the ability to trigger an event after a time, maybe see if `setTimeout` would work, but it's not Dart specific

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not clear if you want a solution which works for Dart in browser or Dart as a console application. But I hope this Dart console application example is somewhat useful for you:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  print('You have 5 seconds! WHAT IS YOUR NAME!!!!');
  final name = await stdin
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: (sink) => sink.add(null))
      .first;

  if (name == null) {
    print('LOL WUT DO YOUR NOT EVEN KNOW YOUR NAME!!!!');
  } else {
    print('I knew it. Your name is $name!');
  }
}
```

Notice that you can call the timeout() method on streams and futures. In my example I use the timeout to add a null event to my stream if no input has been given in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

https://news.dartlang.org/2012/09/use-javascript-code-in-your-dart-apps.html

You can use JavaScript with Dart now. So setTimeout might work.

There is an answer for a built in Dart operation on stack, see below

[How to use setInterval/setTimeout in Dart SDK 0.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295834/how-to-use-setinterval-settimeout-in-dart-sdk-0-4)