# push data to firebase , flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push data to firebase using flutter. I know how to push data to firebase using the add function with the collection name.

I have the speed using the speedometer api , and I want to push the data to firebase every 5s.

please help me to send data without using a button.

Comment: Welcome. Please add some code to show us what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a code that runs every 5 seconds, using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15298728/8572736 together with a statefull widget I was able to come up with this.

in your statefull widget in the initstate add this

```
void initState() {
    future= new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    subscription = future.asStream().listen(PushSpeedToDb());
    super.initState();
  }
```

this will keep calling PushSpeedToDB every 5 seconds
then in your pushSpeedToDB

```
  void PushSpeedToDb() async {
    //await get speed from speed api
    //await add the currentSpeed  the the cloud firestore document
  }
```

In the push speed to db, you can get the speed from the api and add it to your cloud firestore document.

This is how the complete code looks like

```
class SpeedWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SpeedWidgetState();
}

class SpeedWidgetState extends State<SpeedWidget> {
  var future;
  var subscription;
  @override
  void initState() {
    future= new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    subscription = future.asStream().listen(PushSpeedToDb());
    super.initState();
  }
  void PushSpeedToDb() async {
    //await get speed from speed api
    //await add the currentSpeed  the the cloud firestore document
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription?.cancel();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }



}
```