# Randomly show text on the screen flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a text on the screen on random place on random time for some duration.
Position I figured out with the positioned like this : -  but can't figure out how do I do it on the random time.

```
Positioned(
                  top: Random().nextDouble() * 1000,
                  right: Random().nextDouble() * 1000,
                  child: Text(
                    "data",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                );
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer to get a sense of who to do something later in time https://stackoverflow.com/a/15298728/5532723
You just need to make the duration value generated at random time., note that if  the unit is millisecond and you generated a number between 1 and 10, then multiple by 1000 and the function should run at random time (in the future certainly) at random time between 1 and 10 second or 1000 and 10,000 millisecond

Comment: Thanks. But it future would do it once. I need to do it repetitively.

Comment: Check this answer then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946012/how-do-i-run-a-reoccurring-function-in-dart

Comment: Thanks. I Like when someone gives just the way and not the exact code.  That helps learning. Thanks.